# Building fontue tool to generate font set for ReactVR - path_utils.h missing

Tags: oculus, react-360

From the React VR Docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/fonts.html

> It is also possible to generate your own font set textures using the
>   fontue tool in the Oculus Mobile SDK. The tool has a dependency on
>   FreeType, and can be found in the Oculus Mobile SDK Tools/fontue
>   directory, along with a readme.txt describing its operation.

When trying to build the fontue tool in Visual Studio we're getting an error on this include:

include "../common/path_utils.h"

I can't find the path_utils.h in the Oculus Mobile SDK anywhere. Is it supposed to be included somewhere in the package or am i missing something else?

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this question, it has been addressed by the React VR team on Github https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/182